Can't install Debian because of LiveOS dropping to initramfs prompt
I have a problem with the LiveOS on Debian. I had a problem before this one: the mouse and keyboard do not work (they flicker for a bit and then stop) and they drop me into the Gnome DE. I found a solution: to enable IOMMU controlling in the BIOS. But now, I have a different problem.
When booting the system normally (with no failsafe mode), I get a few errors about xhci_hcd and I/O page faults, after that it drops me to the Debian startup screen. Still after that, it drops me into BusyBox, messages before that:
can't setup: -110
init 0000:02:00.0 fail, -110

All from xhci_hcd.
By the way, when I type exit, it says "No supported filesystem images found at /live."
Probably because the directory does not exist. Nomodesets do not help.
Specs:
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780
CPU: AMD FX... I forgot
HDD: 150gb WDC
SSD: 128gb Apacer
USB: 8gb SD card on reader
Debian version: Debian 12
Install method: LiveOS (LiveCD), release
Can somebody help me out?


Update the firmware (UEFI); 2. re-download and verify the ISO; 3. Make sure you're "burning" it to the USB stick correctly.


Meanwhile please [edit] the question and post the actual hardware you're trying to install on, the Debian release/version and how you're doing the installation/live media.

I can't update the firmware because I don't know how...
